# Get timetracking report by logging Git workingcopy branch occupancy

Tags: git, time-tracking

I was wondering if there exist a script (python, or other runnable on windows) that checks every say 1 minute which branch is currently checked out in a git working copy.

That way it would be possible to estimate the time required for each ticket/branch to get a time-tracking report.

Comment: Something like this? `perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e 'while() { print strftime("%FT%T ",localtime); my($branch) = qx(git status -b --porcelain); print $branch; sleep 60}'`

Comment: yes I also thought of a scripting solution but I was wondering if there is there allready a solution that gives me the time that each branch was checked out. But I think I will start a little project on my own since I doupt after 9 hours there will be more answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to this is an implementation in Python:
https://github.com/schoetbi/gitwatch